# modify login prompt or header (/etc/issue) to display ip address of the machine

Tags: linux, ip, prompt

I work with a lot of virtual machines. For testing and preproduction set up.

I would like the login promt or header to display the ip address of the machine. That way when I start it up I can see what IP I will be ssh into. Our network works uses a DHCP. So it can change between boot up.

> $ cat /etc/issue
>   Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l

Which comes up as

> Ubuntu 11.04 [hostname] tty[x]

I want it to come up as

Ubuntu 11.04 [hostname] tty[x] ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I was think about writing an init / upstart script. Is there a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getty does not know machine's ip addresses. But this question was already asked at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/209599/how-to-setup-etc-issues-to-show-the-ip-address-for-eth0). Here's the accepted answer:

> It's just a text file...you write to it the same way you'd send text to a file with any other shell script. Something like this would replace /etc/issue with just your ip address:
>
> ```
> ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/ {print $2}' | cut -f2 -d: > /etc/issue
> ```
>
> Obviously you can make this arbitrarily more complex, depending on what information you want in your `/etc/issue` file.
>
> You can write to this file in your local equivalent of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` (which typically executes after all the other startup scripts).

Also, beware that the file `/etc/issue.net` is used for remote logins so you may want to edit that as well.

Comment: Why would someone need to look at the IP address of a remote system *after* having connected to that system? (that's on the question of modifying the `/etc/issue.net`)

Comment: If you have one hundred servers, and your .ssh/config is configured to distinguish them by hostname, I believe it would be handy to know it's IP address for administration purposes. It's just one of the use cases..

Comment: The IP address can be just looked up with `host`. However, I'd agree that some complex NAT configurations might make a simple lookup not that useful.

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin : I am doing that setup because I am working with some kind of test/dev VM on my personal computer, and since those machines are starting with DHCP, I am not sure with IP they will use.
Adding that allows me to see directly the IP from the console without having to login or anything. Then I can use SSH.

Answer (score 12):

On **CentOS 7** and **Debian 8** (and maybe other as well), just append the following line to `/etc/issue`

```
My IP address: \4
```

and that will resolve to the machine's IPv4 address.
If you have multiple network interfaces and you want to pick one specific, you can specify it with

```
My IP address: \4{eth0}
```

Comment: Also works on openSUSE, for the record.

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS 5 with a DHCP leased IP, you can use this script:

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/issue.sh
#!/bin/bash

update_issue() {
    awk -v \
        r="$(ip -o addr | awk '/inet [1-9]+/ { print $2 " " $4 }')" \
        '{ gsub(/%INTERFACES%/,r) }1' \
        /etc/issue.template > /etc/issue
}

issue_config() {
    update_issue
}

issue_restore() {
    update_issue
}
```

with an issue "template" like this:

```
$ cat /etc/issue.template
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

%INTERFACES%
```

Remember to

```
chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/issue.sh
```

The `awk` command to get the current IP and replace them in the `/etc/issue.template` file should be portable to modern Linux distros.

Comment: Excellent answer.
I find that instead of `ip -o addr` for my purposes eth0 is enough - `r="$(ip address show eth0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)" `

Comment: Smart answer. It's very nice that your answer doesn't simply overwrite /etc/issue with a static value, and that it doesn't simply write a static value once. It's idempotent!